# send file from nextjs API Routes

Tags: node.js, ajax, axios, next.js

I use nextjs API Routes to connect to an external API

when I use a `POST` request to send a file, the file doesn't handled correctly in API Routes and I get `422 Unprocessable Entity Error`

when I send only text it's OK, but when I add a file this error occur.

my request

```
const data = new FormData();
        data.append('first_name', firstName);
        data.append('last_name', lastName);
        data.append('phone_number', phoneNumber);
        image && data.append('avatar', image);

        axios.post(`${API_ROUTE}`, data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        .then(res=>{
            alert(JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 2));
        })
```

my API Route

```
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': req.headers['content-type']
        }
    };

    axios.post(address, req.body, config)
    .then(r=>{
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.json( r.data )
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.json(err)
    })
```

in the request that API Route sending to the external API, there are some `?` in the content of the file, but in the request that sending from browser to the API Route seems there are different characters

Comment: Do you have a multer or formidable , perhaps setup at your middlewares in your nextjs?

Comment: No, I use the nextjs default bodyParser. when i disable it and send the ```req.body``` to the external API it doesn't work and nothing will send. should I use other packages like ```formidable``` to parse the incoming request ?

Comment: yeah, I think you need to get the formData, from the request. but if you are just using the api routes as proxy why not just proxy it directly to your external api using built in nextjs rewrites?

Comment: it was my old challenge, I want to use JWT Authentication, I couldn't store token in ```localStorage``` because I couldn't get it when using ```SSR``` on the server, so I've stored it in the ```cookie``` and use this proxy for both ```server-side``` and ```client-side``` requests to add ```token``` from the incoming request's ```cookie``` to the ```headers``` of the external API's request

Comment: when using ```formidable``` I get file as an ```Object``` with size, path, etc. it saves the file on the server, but I want to get the entire of this binary request, and then sent it to that external API

Comment: @sina9090 i have same question too.